# column not found: 1054 Unknown column in laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to count number of schedules on a homecourt on current timestamp, now I have tried `hasManyThrough` in laravel between homecourt, userhomecourt, schedule but got this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'timeFrom' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tblHomeCourts` where `homeCourtId` = 1 and `timeFrom` <= 1496207469 and `timeTo` > 1496207469)
```

I have these relationship in HomeCourt model

```
public function playerCount()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Schedule::class,UserHomeCourt::class,'homeCourtId','userHomeCourtId','homeCourtId');
}
```

where am I wrong here? please correct it out.

```
class HomeCourt extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblHomeCourts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'homeCourtId';
    protected $appends = ['homeCourtProfilePicUrl'];
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'homeCourtName',
        'cityId',
        'homeCourtProfilePic',
        'gameType',
        'courtType',
        'numberOfCourts',
        'lights',
        'membershipStatus',
        'dayCost',
        'address',
        'lat',
        'long',
        'userId',
        'homeCourtStatus',
    ];
    protected $hidden = ['homeCourtProfilePic', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'homeCourtStatus', 'userId', 'cityId'];

    public function getHomeCourtProfilePicUrlAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->attributes['homeCourtProfilePic'] != "" || $this->attributes['homeCourtProfilePic'] != null) ? Constant::HOMECOURT_PROFILE_URL . $this->attributes['homeCourtProfilePic'] : null;
    }

    /*relation for there now*/
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId');
    }

    /*player count*/
    public function playerCount()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Schedule::class,UserHomeCourt::class,'homeCourtId','userHomeCourtId','homeCourtId');
    }


}
```

Comment: do you have `timeFrom` column in your `tblHomeCourts` table?

Comment: nope it's in schedule table.

Comment: read this `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'timeFrom' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tblHomeCourts` where `homeCourtId` = 1 and `timeFrom` <= 1496207469 and `timeTo` > 1496207469)` it is trying to get `timeFrom` in `tblHomeCourts`

Comment: hmm I know there is mistake in my relationship can you please correct it out?

Comment: please post your full model

Comment: please check the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145509/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-bhavik-bamania).

Comment: Do you have `timeFrom` column?

Comment: yeah in schedule table.